# How to get UTC for date in midnigs in swift

Tags: swift, nsdate, utc, swift2

Can somebody help me to get current UTC date time.
I am trying:

```
let cal = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
        let components = cal.components([.Day , .Month, .Year ], fromDate: NSDate())
        let refDate = cal.dateFromComponents(components)
```

But I am getting `1/12/2017 23:00:00`
This is seems UTC local time.
I want to get UTC for current date at midnight.
In database I save date as number of seconds but on server it is saved as 1/13/2017 00:00:00 and in swift I am getting 1/12/2017 23:00:00 so I can't get values as they are different I don't understand what I need to do to get same UTC.
In database I save date as long number of seconds in swift I am getting it by `UInt64(floor(refDate!.timeIntervalSince1970))` but date is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `hour`, `minute` and `second` property of `NSDateComponents` to `0`

```
let cal = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
cal.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")!
let components = cal.components([.Day , .Month, .Year,.Hour, .Minute, .Second], fromDate: NSDate())
components.hour = 0
components.minute = 0
components.second = 0
let refDate = cal.dateFromComponents(components)
```

Or from iOS 8 you can also use `startOfDayForDate`

```
let cal = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
cal.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")!
let refDate = cal.startOfDayForDate(NSDate())
print(refDate)
```